# Grouping data in pandas for fuzzy logical relationship group

Tags: python, pandas

Im sorry for my bad english.

So I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
    Present State   Next State
0   A13             A13
1   A13             A14
2   A14             A12
3   A12             A14
4   A14             A14
5   A14             A11
6   A11             A11
7   A11             A12
8   A12             A13
9   A13             A12
10  A12             A14
... ...             ...
121 A16             A21
122 A21             A17
123 A17             A16
124 A16             A19
125 A19             A24
126 A24             A24
127 A24             A27
```

and i want to group it based on my intervals dataframe, and i want to count how many transitions made from state a to state b.

I have written a code and it didnt show any error.

```
flrg = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Present State', 'Next State'])
states = intervals["Ai"]
firststate = []
secstate = []
counter = 0
for i in states:
    for index, row in flr.iterrows():
        temp = {}
        if(i == row["Present State"]):
            if row["Next State"] in temp:
                temp[row["Next State"]] += 1
            else:
                temp[row["Next State"]] = 1
    firststate.append(i)
    secstate.append(temp)
flrg["Present State"] = firststate
flrg["Next State"] = secstate

flrg
```

but the results is not right. It only catched one transition.

```
    Present State   Next State
0   A1              {}
1   A2              {}
2   A3              {}
3   A4              {}
4   A5              {}
5   A6              {}
6   A7              {}
7   A8              {}
8   A9              {}
9   A10             {}
10  A11             {}
11  A12             {}
12  A13             {}
13  A14             {}
14  A15             {}
15  A16             {}
16  A17             {}
17  A18             {}
18  A19             {}
19  A20             {}
20  A21             {}
21  A22             {}
22  A23             {}
23  A24             {'A27': 1}
24  A25             {}
25  A26             {}
26  A27             {}
```

what should i do to fix it? I really appreciate your help.

the output should be like this:

```
    Present State   Next State
0   A1              {'A4': 1}
1   A2              {}
2   A3              {'A8': 1}
3   A4              {'A1': 1,'A3': 1,'A4': 1,'A5': 1,'A8': 1}
4   A5              {'A4': 1,'A5': 1,'A6': 1,'A8': 2,'A10': 1}
..  ...             ...
22  A23             {}
23  A24             {'A24': 1,'A27': 1}
24  A25             {}
25  A26             {}
26  A27             {}
```

Comment: What is the expected output look like?

Comment: im sorry. I've updated the expected output in the description. thank you

Comment: I see, you can use `OrderedDict` from `Collections` to store all `Next State` values per key. Your key is the values from the `Present State`.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it. Thank you very much

Comment: the output is still the same. I think the problem is in my conditional statement but i dont know what's wrong